# Puppet: Handling multiple resource attributes in generic way

Tags: puppet

For resources where only one or two attributes are changing, i can use array and hashes respectively. For example, if i have to create files in different directories, i can store the file names and respective paths in a hash and apply them by iterating over the hash. In case if i have more than two attributes that are different, how do i store and iterate over those attributes?

For example, i am trying to create Active Directory groups and i have five attributes and all are different for each group as shown below:

```
 Group_Name      Display Name               Path                     Description            GroupCategory
"My Support"      "Support"    "OU=Groups,OU=DEF,DC=xyz,DC=Com"   "Some decription"           Security
"Prod DBA"          "DBA"      "OU=Groups,OU=XYZ,DC=xyz,DC=Com"   "Different description"   Distribution
...
...
```

UPDATE: Based on the suggestion, here's the code:

```
[root@myhost] cat params.pp
$ad_groups = {
    'Group_Prod' => {
        path        => 'OU=Groups,OU=PROD,DC=TEST,DC=COM',
        displayname => 'Prod Support',
        description => 'Prod Support',
    },

    'Group_App' => {
        path        => 'OU=Groups,OU=APP,DC=TEST,DC=COM',
        displayname => 'App Support',
        description => 'App Support',
    },
}

$ad_groups_defaults = {
    'ensure'        => present,
    'groupscope'    => 'Global',
    'groupcategory' => 'Security',
},


[root@myhost] cat create_groups.pp
class infra::ad::create_groups (
    $ad_groups = $infra::params::ad_groups,
    $ad_groups_defaults = $infra::params::ad_groups_defaults,
) inherits infra::params {
    create_resources(windows_ad::group,$ad_groups,$ad_groups_defaults)
}
```

Now when i try running it, i am getting the following error:

```
Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: "message":"Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Windows_ad::Group[Group_Prod]: default expression for $groupname tries to illegally access not yet evaluated $groupname at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/infra/manifests/ad/create_groups.pp:5 on node puppet.test.com","issue_kind":"RUNTIME_ERROR"}
```

Now if i also add `groupname` attribute in each hash block, the error is resolved. What i want to know is that if my group names are same as the hash keys (in this case, `Group_Prod` and `Group_App`), then can i somehow use those hash keys itself as `groupname` without adding `groupname` attribute in each hash block?

Comment: You can still do this by iterating over the hash and accessing the values from the nested hashes, but you may be more interested in the easy way of doing this with the `create_resources` function: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/function.html#createresources

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard. Kindly check my UPDATE section.

Comment: `windows_ad::group` is a defined resource type, correct? You can set default values for parameters/attributes in the defined resource definition via something like `windows_ad::group(..., $groupname = $title, ...)` so `$groupname` is set to the resource title by default, which would be the hash key in this situation.

Comment: No. It's a [module](https://forge.puppet.com/jriviere/windows_ad) from Puppet forge.

Comment: In this case where i'm using a module from Puppet forge, is there a way i can use the title as `$groupname`?

Comment: Nothing off the top of my head, but there might be a way.